# Is there a more efficient way to store an n-ary tree in a file in C?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

Say I'm writing an adventure game.  The map is built of tiles of different types.  I have tiles that form paths, and tiles that form doors, and so on.

I will use a struct to describe the type and content of a tile, and to which other tiles it connects.

Then I'll make a quadruple-linked list to connect them all together.

But a struct that will describe a room will have far more elements than one that will describe a door, so many elements in a door struct will be redundant.  I could make a smaller door struct, but structs can only point to structs of the same type*, so I couldn't connect a room struct to a door struct.  The redundancy may be negligible but I wondered if there's another way.

Another option is using an array of structs, but then I'd have lots of 'padding' structs wasting even more space.  However an array would make reading and re-building a map from file much easier.

Is there any way around the limitation that a struct can only point to a struct of the same type?  Or is there another common solution to this problem that I haven't mentioned?

One idea I had was that each tile could have pointers for every other type of tile.  Some would be redundant, but it would be a lesser redundancy that the option above.

*By this I mean that typically in a linked list, structs contain pointers to struct of the same type that they're in.

Comment: Structs can point to objects of any type. Why do you say that they can "only point to a struct of the same type"?

Comment: @Marc Typically in a linked list, each struct has a pointer to the same type of struct in which it exists.  That's what I meant.  In my case, I have different types of structs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't have to have a uniform struct describing everything. Instead, you could do the following (this is somewhat like writing your own C++ virtual tables in C, and is very widely used).

Your basic tile struct can look like this:

```
struct tile
{
    // common tile stuff
    ...
    enum tile_type type;
    void *type_info;
};
```

So in this struct you store stuff that's common to every tile type. Then you make other structs for other types: one for a room, one for a path, etc. Within an object of `tile`, you make the `enum` describe the actual type, and store a pointer to the concrete type within the `void *`.

---

There are many links describing variations of this technique. [Here](http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/programming-pointers/4391967/Virtual-functions-in-C)'s one.

Comment: That's a good idea.  I'd still need to somehow index elements after reading from a file, but I hadn't even thought about using void pointers.  Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing elements in a tile, store only a pointer to the linked list of elements.